# Vue.js code wont deploy to firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I created a vue.js app using d3.js. I want to deploy my code to a public website where I can access it 24/7. I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@rachidsakara/how-to-deploy-vue-js-applications-with-firebase-hosting-40cfa7f724e4) however after I run the command

```
firebase deploy
```

the webpage [image: the webpage] looks like this. I think this means that my code either is not running or it did not deploy properly.

after I run the command

```
firebase init
```

and move my .vue, .json, and .js to the public folder this is what my directory looks like

[image: directory]

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction, please? In order for the program to run properly I have a .json file with geojson to plot a floorplan.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Firebase Hosting public directory is in "Floormap-app/public".  This would likely be the case if you didn't change any of the defaults in firebase.json.  If you want a different directory, such as "Floormap-app/floormap", where I see you have an index.html, you will have to modify the configuration of the public folder in firebase.json.